# React Native - Undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, json, react-native

I want to get the last item of a json response.

When i do `console.log(this.state.details.sessions)` it shows me following json object.

```
[{"login_time": "12-04-2021 20:52:29", "logout_time": ""}, {"login_time": "12-04-2021 20:54:53", "logout_time": "12-04-2021 20:55:13"}]
```

But if try to get the length of this item like:
`Object.keys(this.state.details.sessions).length` i get this following error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(data.sessions)')

```
const {number} = this.props.route.params;
database().ref('/numbers/'+number.replace('+', ''))
          .on('value', (snapshot) => {
            const userObj = snapshot.val();
            this.setState({
                details: userObj
          })
});

console.log(Object.keys(this.state.details.sessions).length);
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: `data.sessions[data.sessions.length - 1];` to get the last item

Comment: @decpk just updated the post, it still shows me a error. "(undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.sessions.length')

Comment: So it was [how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) after all. I got a bit confused, because the structure was nested, and you are using `Object.keys` on an array, but oh well.

Comment: @ASDFGerte can you please explain me how to do it in the right way?

Answer (score 0):

in the very first `this.state.details.sessions` is `undefined`, you cannot use `Object.keys` on that

after you set data into that

```
this.setState({
  details: userObj,
});
```

`this.state.details.sessions` is actually an array